# Macbook Pro Retina Early 2015 bootcamp

Tags: macos

My bootcamp doesn't have the 'selected tasks' 
Please help! I really need windows on my mac. 
Thank you :)
[image]

Comment: If you are ok with it, you can follow my tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJE4OyT0DXg).

Comment: I followed your steps but it did not work anyways thanks I appreciate it. Since my the 'select task' window is not appearing in my bootcamp.

Comment: When opening bootcamp, is there a back button you can click? Edit: Nevermind, stupid question. I can see in the picture you posted there is a Go Back Button.

Comment: Don't use illegal copies of software.

Comment: When I open bootcamp the introduction page open but when I press continue this is the page that opens. If you have any idea please help.

Comment: What do you want to open then?

Comment: I want to open the 'select task'

Answer (score 1):

In your window, click the "Go Back" button until you get to the selection screen.

***Note: Also, don't get illegal copies of OSes. If you want a free copy of Windows 10, sign up for the Windows Insider Program. You can get a free ISO file from there.***